# Returning a logical vector for matches: regexp supported?

Tags: regex, r

I want to return a logical vector for regexp matches over a character vector, but match or %in do not seem to support regular expressions, e.g.:

```
> x <- c("Bill", "Brett", "Jane")
> grep("^B", x)
[1] 1 2
> x %in% "^B"
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I would like this to return

```
[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

Ideas?

Thanks,

Roberto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just chain it:

```
> seq(along=(x)) %in% grep("^B", x)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
```

So you could write yourself a little helper function that does both as shown here. But I presume one of the `grep()` variants does that as well...  Ah, yes, `grepl()` is your friend:

```
> grepl("^B", x)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
```

Nothing that a quick `help(grep)` can't cure ;-)

Comment: @comment : two times we post simultaneously today :-) You're really lurking the questions, no? I deleted my answer, as you added that to your post.

Comment: @Joris: wow, the same three answers inside of one minute... I deleted mine as well.

Comment: @Joshua : seems like we need more questions to fulfill the answering needs of us. Maybe we should mention the existence of this site on the mailing list of R as well. I guess they won't mind losing a bit of traffic there...

Comment: @Joris, perhaps but you have to ask yourself if you *really* want some of that traffic. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One way is just to wrap two simple steps up in a function, where we get `grep()` to do it's thing, but supply the indices of the elements in `x` as the LHS of the call to `%in%`:

```
foo <- function(x, pattern, ...) {
    seq_along(x) %in% grep(pattern, x, ...) 
}
```

With your example data we get:

```
> x <- c("Bill", "Brett", "Jane")
> foo(x, pattern = "^B")
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grepl`:

```
> x <- c("Bill", "Brett", "Jane") 
> grepl("^B", x) 
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

**Edit**

Ooops, seems Dirk already had this further down his answer. For the sake of novelty, here's some other ways:

```
> ans <- rep(FALSE,length(x))
> ans[grep("^B",x)]<-TRUE
> ans
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE


> 1:length(x) %in% grep("^B",x)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```