# subseting with grep in data.table - unpredicatble

Tags: r, data.table

Why is "grep" causing problems in the below data.table calls.

```
set.seed(45)
dt <- data.table(
    col1 = sample(letters[1:2],10, replace=TRUE), 
    col2=sample(letters[1:5], 10, replace=TRUE),
    col3=runif(10,1,5))
```

Subsetting like this, works:

```
dt[col1=="b" & col2=="b",] # Works
    col1 col2     col3
1:    b    b    1.5166
```

But this throws a warning and returns wrong data (or no warning and wrong data)

```
dt[grep("b", col1) & col2=="b",] # does not
# with seed = 42
> Warning message: In grep("b", col1) & col2 == "b" :   longer object
> length is not a multiple of shorter object length
# with seed = 45
   col1 col2     col3
1:    b    b 1.516600
2:    a    b 3.342007
3:    a    b 1.865772
```

I can avoid this confusion by tying the subsets together:

```
dt[grep("b", col1),][col2=="b",]
```

But that is not very elegant.

ps. I guess the problem is different than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993311/r-losing-data-during-subsetting-data-table)

Comment: You need to use `grepl` as `grep` returns a numeric index. i.e. `dt[grepl("b", col1) & col2=="b"]`

Comment: aah - how could I make that mistake. So off course. Thanks!.  Please write this as an answer - so that I can accept it.

Comment: Am I missing something? You don't need to use a regex; just use `col1=="b" & col2=="b"`. In case you do need a regex, you might like the alias offered in data.table: `col1 %like% "b" & col2 == "b"`

Comment: Possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3840183/1191259

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output of `grep` is a numeric `vector`.  It can be of `length` anywhere between 0 to the length of the original `vector` depending on how many matches are there.  But, if we use `grepl`, the return `vector` is `logical` and it will always be of the same `length` as the original vector.  If there are no matches, only difference is that it will be all `FALSE`.  In that respect, the below code should work fine.

```
dt[grepl("b", col1) & col2=="b"]
```